# Meaning the "of" clause in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions, complements

is the "of" clause used correctly in the 2nd sentence? If so, what is the difference between the 1st and 2nd.

> she is pretty
>
> she is of pretty

Comment: *She is **of** pretty* is completely unidiomatic. It has no meaning in English.

Comment: Hm.. I understand @StoneyB but where can i use "to be of" ?

Comment: To be of value, to be of interest, to be of importance are examples of the usage.  The general idea is to use the noun instead of the adjective, and precede it with of:  valuable/of value, interesting/of interest, and so on.  So, yours is wrong on two counts: pretty is an adjective, not a noun, and we simply don't use "of prettiness".

Comment: but you can say something is a thing of great beauty. i have never heard that said of people though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Of* is a preposition and requires a noun or nominal as its object: *of NOUN*.

To express *She is ADJECTIVE* with an *of* phrase, you have to convert *ADJECTIVE* into the *NOUN* which names its quality. *Old*, for instance, would become *age*, *beautiful* would become *beauty*, and so forth. It is then grammatical to use *of QUALITY* as a complement of *BE*—MdMazzotti gives you a few examples—but the construction is literary and I think unproductive in spoken English. Even in written English *of QUALITY* is far more often found modifying a noun rather than as a predicate nominative:

> <sup>ok</sup> She is a woman of beauty, *BUT*
>   <sup>?</sup>   She is of beauty.

Moreover, there are not many adjectives which will survive this conversion. *Pretty*, for instance, would have to become *prettiness*, and this will not work at all:

> <sup>∗</sup>  She is of prettiness.

A slightly more common construction is *BE a NOUN of ADJECTIVE QUALITY*:

> She is a woman of great beauty.
>   Parkinson was a scholar of undoubted probity.
>   Lord Darrowby was a blackguard of a vicious and unrestrainable temper.

My advice to you is that you avoid constructions of these sorts altogether, until you are widely read in English literature of the past century or so and have an intuitive understanding of when they can and cannot be employed. Unless you become a novelist or literary critic it is unlikely you will ever need them.

Comment: Another popular is - *He's a gem of person.*

Comment: @MaulikV "He's a gem of a person"?

Comment: @TarkaDaal Aw, sorry. Yes, *a gem of a person*

Answer (score 2):

You can use "to be of" in a sentence like this:

You are of a rare beauty.

The dog is of a breed that is predisposed to aggressive behaviour.

I am of the idea that...